# Error when using \sqrt[n]{x} as a label in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

I am trying to use \sqrt[n]{x} as a label in tikzcd, however there seems to be a problem with the [n] as when I run it with just \sqrt{x} there's no problem. Don't suppose anyone knows a way around this? The error is given below.

[image: Error given by Code]

[image: Full Code]

[image: Code Output]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hello and welcome among us. please read this topic about MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: You need `"{\sqrt[n]{x}}"`.

Comment: You're a saint, thank you! :)